# How can I controll an Bootstrap Dropdown programmatically (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I have the following Dropdown in my View, and I wanna open/close it from my typescript class. How would I go on to do that?

Thanks for any help!

```
 <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn" id="cartDropdown" ngbDropdownToggle>Warenkorb<img class="warenkorbNavbar"
          src="../assets/img/shopping-cart.png" /></button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="cartDropdown">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the dropdown from within the TS file by using `@ViewChild()`.

Add a template variable to the `ngbDropdown` for example `#dropdown`

```html
<div #dropdown ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown
  </button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use `@ViewChild()` in your typescript file. You can then call the open method on the dropdown from within the typescript

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-basic',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdDropdownBasic {
  @ViewChild(NgbDropdown, { static: true })
  public dropdown: NgbDropdown;

  public toggleDropdown(): void {
    this.dropdown.open();
  }
}
```

A working Stackblitz example...

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vbmva

Comment: if you use a reference variable use in the way `<div #dropdown="ngbDropdown" ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">` (see that you indicate Angular that it's a ngbDropDown. So in .ts you can use `@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown` -the `{static:true}`it's only in case your dropdown is always visible -not under a *ngIf-. When you use ViewChild, you can use also `@ViewChild('dropdown', { read:NgbDropdown})`. Futhermore, you can pass the dropdown as argument of one function in .html. e.g. `(click)="doSomething(dropdown)"` or even `(click)="dropdown.toggle()"`